# How to get request and response size in jquery without parsing request and response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, getjson

The common approach to get the size of HTTP request and response size using jquery is to fetch them from the response using getResponseHeader("Content-Lenght") however, I have problem using this because of cross-domain call I use via getJSON. Is there any way we can calculate the size of request and response without browser data? Suppose counting bits of the request in javscript and counting the response size in PhP?

Comment: have you tried an AJAX jsonp request?  that works across domains if you only want to GET json

Comment: I am using getJSON and can get everything done, i.e. sending my data and receiving the results from the server. But, I need to measure the size of data I am sending and the size of response I am receiving from PhP server.

Comment: so you aren't getting an error indicating a same origin policy violation?

Comment: no I actually use "?callback=?" at the end of url address. Thus, my call is treated like JSONP.

Comment: What is the type of result you receive ? if it's a string (like for HTML content) you just have to retrieve the length property. if it's an object, you can try to stringify it in order to do the same as string (retrieve length).

Comment: the result is an array of numbers prepared in json object. I don't want to measure the data length, rather I want the total communication overhead. I am looking at the point to see how much networking raise in my app.